# How to get only the uppercase first letters in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, abbreviation

I want to transform phrases in abbreviations, but don't want every first letter of the words to compose the abbreviation, only the ones that are in uppercase. For example, I'd like to transform the string "United States of America" into "USA" and not "USOA", as all the codes I found works.

In my project I have to show a timetable of classes, and some of the classes names are big like "Linguagem de Programação Orientada a Objeto" (object-oriented programming language), and if I use the codes I found on the internet, it would turn the "Linguagem de Programação Orientada a Objeto" string into LDPOAO, and not LPOO, as it would make sense.

**The code I found: (it turns a string into an abbreviation, I want to know how to select only the uppercase letters to put in $result)**

```
$string = "Progress in Veterinary Science";

$expr = '/(?<=\s|^)[a-z]/i';
preg_match_all($expr, $string, $matches);

$result = implode('', $matches[0]);

$result = strtoupper($result);

echo $result;
```

Comment: That code doesn't look for upper case characters.

Comment: Yes, I know, that code just turns the string into an abbreviation. My question is how I select only the uppercase first letters and put in the $result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the code. Note the changes to the regular expression:

```
$string = "Progress in Veterinary Science";

$expr = '/(?<=\s|^)[A-Z]/';
preg_match_all($expr, $string, $matches);    
$result = implode('', $matches[0]);
echo $result;
```

Comment: Thanks, note that I'm just beginning to learn PHP (and by myself) so I didn't knew that the 'i' made it case-insensitive.

Comment: `$result = strtoupper($result);` is redundant.

Comment: I was waiting to accept it, I tried it right when I answered but I needed to wait some minutes.

Answer (score 4):

IMO, it seems alot easier to simply remove all characters that are not in uppercase format.

```
$str = 'United States of America';
$str = preg_replace('~[^A-Z]~', '', $str);
echo $str; // "USA"
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex will look for upper case characters, note the removed `i` and `[A-Z]` as upper case.

```
$expr = '/(?<=\s|^)[A-Z]/';
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should really try to understand regular expressions.

The one you're using to get the first letter of each word has a modifier at the end (the `i` character after the final slash) that makes the regex case insensitive.

In your case, you want just uppercase letters, so you should remove the `i` modifier, and change the desired letters (the `[a-z]` part) to uppercase (`[A-Z]`). So the regex becomes:

```
$expr = '/(?<=\s|^)[A-Z]/';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 function abbreviate ($string) {
    $in = explode(" ", $string);
    $abbr = '';
    foreach ($in AS $key => $input) {
        preg_match("/^([A-Z]+)/", $input, $matches);
        $abbr = (isset($matches[0])) ? $abbr.$matches[0] : $abbr;
    }
    return $abbr;
}

echo abbreviate("United States of America");
```